# Google Recaptcha Domain Name Validation disabled not rendering captcha

Tags: recaptcha

As per google documentation

> **Domain Name Validation**  A reCAPTCHA key is normally tied to a set of
>   individual domains. However, if your list of valid domains is
>   extremely long, fluid, or unknown, we give you the option to turn off
>   the domain name checking on reCAPTCHA's end, and instead check on your
>   server.
>
> To do so, in the admin console, go to "Advanced Settings" for your
>   key, and untick the "Domain Name Validation" box.

I have generated key and unchecked the domain validation check, but when I am using that site key to show captcha, its not working. *It is showing ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key.*

What is the way to implement same key for multiple domains for Google Recaptcha V2.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, this seems to be a bug that has not been solved yet.

The following workaround works: make sure the "Verify the origin..." option is checked. Fill in any domain in 'Domains' section, uncheck the "Verify the origin..." option. This will work, and no longer gives the "Invalid site key" error.